# Generate Table/Grid from script in Adobe InDesign

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe, adobe-indesign

Documentation doesn't help at all,no Table or Grid is specified...(or I cant find it)

I tried to create a grid from inside InDesign and it shows up as TextFrame,but still I dont understand how to manage it.

The tool I need to do takes a file(CSV/JSON) and generates a Table(or whatever is called in Adobe) from it,but the problem is that I can't find anything about Table generation.

Comment: See [Table](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#Table.html) in the docs for InDesign ExtendScript API.

Comment: @RobC it's not exactly helpful link if he wants to create a new table from a text rather than to modify existed one. I'd advice to look for the method `convertToTable()` of the `Text` object https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#Text.html for this purpose

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution? Could you provide some feedback?

Comment: Nope,I found a easier way to do what I had to

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can make a table from a selected text with the method `convertToTable()` this way:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;                  // your document
var frame = doc.pages[0].textFrames[0];        // first text frame on first page
frame.texts.everyItem().select();              // select all text inside the frame
var table = app.selection[0].convertToTable(); // convert the selection into a table
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Text](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#Text.html) object

As for the rest... it's need more details about your workflow. JSON and CSV are quite different beasts, it would be different parsing algorithms for each of the formats. Will you copy the contents of the files manually or the script should read all csv or json files from some predefined folder? Or there should be some interface to select a file(s). Or a folder? How it supposed to handle a page size and formatting of the table? Etc...